# How to off grid in 3d plot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, 3d

I have a script for 3d plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=[5,3])
ax = fig.gca(projection = '3d')
ax.set_ylim(0,3)
ax.set_zlim(0,2)
```

I read [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/removing-grid-and-plot-manipulation-on-pyplot-3d-figures/4256) that

```
ax=gca()
ax[:set_axis_off]()
```

will help. How to apply that?

I tried:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[5,3])
ax = fig.gca(projection = '3d')
ax[:set_axis_off]()
ax.set_ylim(0,3)
ax.set_zlim(0,2)
```

with an error:

```
/usr/lib/python3.6/_collections_abc.py:841: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: 
The text.latex.unicode rcparam was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.0 and will be removed in 3.2.
  self[key] = other[key]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "axes.py", line 16, in <module>
    ax[:set_axis_off]()
NameError: name 'set_axis_off' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [example you found](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/removing-grid-and-plot-manipulation-on-pyplot-3d-figures/4256/3), is for the Julia programming language.

The Python syntax for this is different: `ax.set_axis_off()`

Comment: Thank you and does exist a command that completly delete the grit not only hide it?

Comment: `ax.set_zticks`, see [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.html?highlight=set_zticks#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.set_zticks) .